# setView() dictionary in R Shiny Leaflet Maps

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, maps, zooming

I'm currently creating a RShiny Application that uses Leaflet Map. As a feature, I need to zoom into certain continents (based on the users choice).

- Is there a `setView()` dictionary for each of the continents (ex. Asia, Africa, etc)?
- Is there also another way of figuring out the `setView()` based on points on the map?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many resources online such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_midpoint_of_Asia

Comment: does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the photon package:

```
library(photon)
library(leaflet)
location <- "Africa"
geo <- geocode(location, limit = 1, key = "place")
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(lng = geo$lon, lat = geo$lat, zoom  = 3)
```